# Trouble understanding static class in iOS

Tags: ios, static

I am following the Big Nerd Ranch book on iOS programming.

There is a sample of a static class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRItemStore : NSObject

+ (BNRItemStore *) sharedStore;

@end
```

---

I have a problem undrstanding the bit below with question mark in the comments.
If I try to alloc this class, the overriden method will bring me to `sharedStore`, which in turn sets the static pointer `sharedStore` to nil.  The conditional after will hit the first time because the pointer doesn't exist.

The idea is that the second time I am in the same place, it would not alloc a new instance and get the existing instance instead. However with `static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;` I am setting the pointer to nil and destroy it, isn't it? Hence every time I am creating unintentionally a new instance, no?

```
#import "BNRItemStore.h"

@implementation BNRItemStore

+ (BNRItemStore*) sharedStore
{
    static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil; // ???
    if (!sharedStore) {
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    }
    return sharedStore;
}

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self sharedStore];
}

@end
```

Comment: What you have is a so-called "singleton" pattern.  The most confusing part is that the statement beginning `static` isn't executed as part of the enclosing method, but is executed only once, when the class loads.

Comment: (I hope the book doesn't actually call that a "static class".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However with `static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;` I am setting the pointer to `nil` and destroy it, isn't it?

No, you do not set it to `nil`: the expression in the `static` initializer is computed only once; the second time around the initialization has no effect. This looks very confusing, but this is the way the function-static facility works in C (and by extension, in Objective-C).

Try this as an example:

```
int next() {
    static int current = 123;
    return current++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%d", next());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This would produce a sequence of increasing numbers starting at 123, even though the code makes it appear as if `current` is assigned 123 every time that you go through the function.