# Static variables not overwritten?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, static

I am doing some exercises in Objective-C and one of the exercises involves creating an instance of an object called `BNRItemStore`. The method that is used is the following

```
+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
     static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;
     if(!sharedStore)
     {
          sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
     }

     return sharedStore
}
```

In the explanation it says that only the first time that sharedStore is called will an instance of BNRItemStore be created and the sharedStore set to point to it. Any subsequent calls will simply return the already-created one. They also explain that a static variable in Obj-C is not destroyed when the method is done executing.

Even with that being said, if you call `sharedStore` the first time and a new instance of `BNRItemStore` is created and then call the same method again, wont another new instance be created and the `sharedStore` pointer set to point to the new instance? This seems logical because even with the static variable, the first line of the method sets the static pointer to nil, effectively erasing the current (if it exists) pointer, right?

Edit: To help clear up any confusion, here is the full code of the implementation file currently:

```
@implementation BNRItemStore

+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
    static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;
    // Do I need to create a sharedStore?
    if (!sharedStore)
    {
        sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
    }

    return sharedStore;
}

// If a programmer calls [[BNRItemStore alloc] init], let him
// know the error of his ways
- (instancetype)init
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Singleton"
                                   reason:@"Use +[BNRItemStore sharedStore]"
                                 userInfo:nil];
    return nil;
}

// Here is the real (secret) private initializer
- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _privateItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using init. Get rid of the initPrivate and use init only. It works nicely when "a user" calls it. Just return _sharedStore instead of self. Especially when you use ARC, this works nicely. However, it is not driectly related to your question.

Comment: Check out this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724522/trouble-understanding-static-class-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write `!sharedStore` is `sharedStore == nil`. This may help clarify things.

The first time, `sharedStore` is initialized to `nil`.

That first time, `sharedStore == nil` is true, so `sharedStore` is assigned a value (this will give it a value which is not `nil`).

The next time, `sharedStore` is not initialized, the value from the previous call is preserved.

That next time, `sharedStore == nil` is false, so `sharedStore` is not assigned a value.

---

The confusion here is over the line `static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;`

This is not assignment, this is initialization. They look similar, but they are not the same.

```
type x = value; // This initializes a new variable with value.
x = differentValue; // This assigns an existing variable with a different value.
```

Static variables are only initialized once. No matter how many times the method is called, it will only be initialized the first time.

I guess you can think of it as skipping that line of code in subsequent calls.

NOTE: This is not just Objective-C, this is also true in C and C++.

Comment: So in Obj-C, when you initialize a static varibale to nil, and then modify it to point to an actual object, the next time you try to set it to nil the code will skip it and not set it to nil? What I am trying to say that since the first line of the method will ALWAYS set sharedStore to nil, the next if statement will always execute since it was just set to nil in the line above. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation BNRItemStore

static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;

+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{

    // Do I need to create a sharedStore?
    if (!sharedStore)
    {
        sharedStore = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedStore;
}

// Here is the real (secret) private initializer
- (instancetype)init
{
    // if you really want to raise an exception here, then simply compare 
    // self == sharedStore. When they are not equal then raise the exception here. 
    if (!sharedStore) {

        sharedStore = [super init];
    }
    return sharedStore;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sharedStore method is not threadsafe. You must use @synchronized or better dispatch once to make it threadsafe.

```
@implementation BNRItemStore

static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;

+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
    // Creates a sharedStore using dispatch once
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
           sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
         });
    return sharedStore;
}

// Here is the real (secret) private initializer
- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _privateItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And instead of throwing an exception when a programmer wants to use a init method on your class, just make the compiler create an error for him/her so that the programmer know that he/she is dealing with a singleton.(nicer than crashing at runtime).

Add these lines on your singleton's .h file.

```
+(instancetype) alloc __attribute__((unavailable("alloc not available, call sharedInstance instead")));
-(instancetype) init  __attribute__((unavailable("init not available, call sharedInstance instead")));
+(instancetype) new   __attribute__((unavailable("new not available, call sharedInstance instead")));
```

**Update:**

Calling `[self alloc]` is perfectly valid and it won't give any problem. I disagree with @mah's answer about this part. Read more about caring and feeding singletons here.

https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html